# Find non modified tables in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to find the tables which were not updated in last 30 days in snowflake, I found that we can check latest updated tables using :

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       last_altered as modify_time
from information_schema.tables
where last_altered > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by last_altered desc;
```

So what we can do here to get tables which were not updated in 30 days, In short we want to exclude the tables returned by above query from information_schema.tables.

could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.
Just change `>` to `<`.

```
   select table_schema, table_name, last_altered as modify_time
   from information_schema.tables
   where last_altered < DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   order by last_altered desc;
```

If you still do not get the correct data; just exclude the results of above query in your post using [not in](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/in) conditional expression function.

```
select 
  table_schema, table_name, last_altered as last_altered_date
from 
  information_schema.tables
where 
  table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and (table_schema, table_name) not in (
    select table_schema,table_name
    from information_schema.tables
    where last_altered > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
 ) order by last_altered_date desc;
```

Comment: Hello, I can see that I am able to retrieve the tables which are non modified after 30 days, but If I add Latest modified tables for 30 days + Tables non modified after 30 days the count dose not match total no of tables in information schema, could you suggest something

Comment: `Hello, I can see that I am able to retrieve the tables which are non modified after 30 days` : Happy to help you for your original question.


`but If I add Latest modified tables for 30 days + Tables non modified after 30 days the count dose not match total no of tables in information schema, could you suggest something`


During this; are you passing the `table_schema`?

Comment: There can be one reason;

The `non modified tables` exactly 30 days from now are not counted in either of the query.

And So the total count is less than the expected.

Can you please confirm whether 
`Latest modified tables for 30 days + Tables non modified after 30 days` this count is less than the expected when you run both queries seperately ?

Comment: Yes that is true I ran both queries separately and they do not match the total no of tables present

Comment: Well,
Can you try : `equal to` also
`where last_altered = DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`;
And check, which tables were modified on 30th day before now ?

Comment: If you want to include `last_altered = DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` in your query;

We can change this as 

 `last_altered <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Also;
Please do not forget to accept the answer / upvote it; if answer and the followed explanation has addressed your queries.

Comment: Yes sure, I tried using last_altered <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); but it gives the same result

Comment: As you already have;  `last_altered` date;
Can you please tell me `last_altered` date if any; from whole records; from this `table_schema` which records are not included in either of the query result.


You are already comparing both lists;

Comment: We have total 372 records, when I check for latest 30 days it gives me 29 and when I check for after 30 days using your query it gives me 171 records, an example record which is not preset in both has modify time as 21-06-2022  23:31:52

Comment: Does my second query with `not in` also gives you the same result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252318/discussion-between-jensen-and-tushar).

Comment: when I use this select table_schema,
table_name,
last_altered as modify_time
from information_schema.tables
where last_altered > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by last_altered desc;
It give me 29

Comment: When I use
select table_schema, table_name, last_altered as last_altered_date
from
information_schema.tables
where
table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and (table_schema, table_name) not in (
select table_schema,table_name
from information_schema.tables
where last_altered > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
) order by last_altered_date desc;
It gives me 171

Comment: and for this
select
table_schema, table_name, last_altered as last_altered_date
from
information_schema.tables
it gives 373 records

Comment: Are you adding `table_type = 'BASE TABLE` in your query.

Also;
Can you cross-verify there are any example tables in any example schema ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the operator from greater than to less than.

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       last_altered as modify_time
from information_schema.tables
where last_altered < DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by last_altered desc;
```

Comment: Hello, I can see that I am able to retrieve the tables which are non modified after 30 days, but If I add Latest modified tables for 30 days + Tables non modified after 30 days the count dose not match total no of tables in information schema, could you suggest something

Comment: In my case it shows the correct number of tables. Can you please check if your where condition is correctly written.

SELECT COUNT(1)
from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' -- 208 tables
and last_altered > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)    --181 tables updated in last 30 days
--and last_altered < DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)    --27 tables not updated in last 30 days